# Macro definition for ".global"

Tags: c, macros

I have a "c" program that uses ".global" assembly language code. My compiler does not allow this, i need to ignore the same, i tried the following:

```
#define .global //global
```

But this gives a compiler error. Is there any other option that I can use. The compilation error is:

"expected an identifier"

Comment: What compiler do you use? Can you show us an example of this usage?

Comment: Literally the text `.global` appears in the C source file?

Comment: ".global _vsf_getps;" this how it is used, I use an in house compiler, which does not support this construct, so need to ignore this while compilation, without changing the actula code

Comment: yes ".global" appear in .c files

Comment: Why can't you change the code?

Comment: You'll probably need to wrap them in `#ifdef...#endif` constructs.  Alternatively, you _might_ be able to globally replace `.global` with, say, `GLOBAL` and then conditionally `#define GLOBAL //nothing` or `#define GLOBAL .global` depending on the compiler... depends on whether the older compiler looks for the `.global` lines before or after pre-processing.

Comment: It smells like a section in your linker script. You must understand what .global does in you in-house compiler. If you add this info, probably someone can give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly going to end up writing your own preprocessing script; it shouldn't be too difficult, if your source files are reasonably controlled. If you don't use the `.global` construct in string literals or comments, for example, it would be sufficient to do something like:

```
sed  's/.global [_[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*;//g'
```

(perhaps with a bit more attention to detail about whitespace).

---

You cannot manufacture a comment with a macro. (You also cannot define a macro whose name starts with a `.`, although I suppose there could be a compiler which accepts that as an extension.)

Comments are replaced with whitespace in phase 3 of the translation process. Preprocessor directives are not examined until phase 4, by which time all the comments have disappeared.

So there is no difference between

```
#define COMMENT //comment
#define COMMENT
```

---

Standards reference: §5.1.1.2/1:

3. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens7) and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. Each comment is replaced by one space character.…
4. Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and `_Pragma` unary operator expressions are executed.…